# SQL DB corruption recovery procedure

Tags: sql-server

I've like to have this discussion on db corruption topic. We run weekly dbcc checkdb and most time, this sql job went through without errors. However, if it does, that usually means big headache for any dbas.

The recommended way is to check if it can be fixed without data loss or restore from last good copy.

My question is about the procedure to restore from last good copy.

Our backup strategy is weekly full back on sunday, diff backup daily and tlog backup hourly.

Say if weekly integrity check indicated errors,

How to determine the last good backup
once last good backup is determined, say corruption on wed, should I use last week full backup + diff backup on tuesday + all tlogs after tuesday's diff backup till current time to restore db? question
should I use replace option ?

Comment: Your question boils down to "how to restore a database"; is there anything specific in the product documentation that remains unclear?

Comment: yes , would tlog contain corrupted data? diff backup is not usable after corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer as shortly as possible:

Yes, a restoring a chain of log backup can "clean up" a correction.

- Restore a full backup taken when the database was healthy.
- Possibly also diff backup. But if you restore a diff backup from when the corruption existed, then there's a risk that the corrupt pages are in that diff backup.
- Then restore an unbroken chain of log backups.

Before all the restore operations you want to take the "last log backup" (aka tail-log backup) if possible, so you lose zero data.

You can start this restore sequence by restoring only what is corrupt. Either at the page level as suggested by MBuschi, or at file or filegroup level (assuming file/filegroup don't include/affect the primary filegroup). This can be beneficial of the database is large. For smaller databases it is likely that "messing about with how things work" can lead to a longer restore process compared to beginning with a full restore.

Comment: Thanks Tibor. Seems page level restoration requires native sql backup . In my situation, some of db were backed up using third party app and files went into third party vault directly. There is no chance to get  .bak or .trn files out of third party app

Comment: Your 3:rd party backup solution could support restoring a part of a database (page level, for instance), technically. Whether or not it does is for you to find out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Enterprise license, one could perform a page-level restore while the database is online. The process is nothing but actually swapping the corrupt data page(s) with a copy of data pages from the backup. On other editions of the SQL Server, the recovery would be an offline process, meaning, the database has to be offline during the restore.

Browse Object-Explorer, right-click the database
Go to tasks, select Restore and click Page….

[image]

In the restore page window, click the button at the top, Check Database Pages. This would identify the pages that it suspects are inconsistent, by executing the DBCC command, DBCC CHECKDB PHYSICAL_ONLY.

[image]

Specify the backup files to pull the data from by taking a look at the files in the backup sets section. Press the Verify button. You’ll see at the top that the backup media was verified successfully.

[image]

The database will go through the process of restoring the clean pages and a message on whether the process was successful or not would be displayed. we can see that the database restored successfully. Go ahead and press the OK button.

Comment: ... and FWIW, page restore is available on lower editions also, but that is not as online operations. I.e., the database is unavailable until the pages and subsequent log backups are restored.

Comment: Thanks MBuschi.  Some of Databases have been backed up by Commvault SQL and db backup goes into commvault space directly. In this case, page level restoration is off the table as it requires physical .bak/trn files  ?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure. Usually the disadvantage of using third party backup solution is to lose some functionality like this.

Answer (score 0):

The time when corruption is reported, whether detected when loading a page into the buffer (reported in the errorlog and generating a dump) or by checkdb, is different from WHEN it was introduced.
Due to the very nature of the problem, there is no way to tell WHEN corruption happened, only that it happened. So to answer your question:

"How to determine the last good backup?"

As part of your BACKUP Strategy, you should checksum your backups but also TEST them. You can have a secondary instance for this and run checkdb periodically to monitor the health of your data without putting much stress into your main database.

More information on checksum and errors during [backup/restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/possible-media-errors-during-backup-and-restore-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/possible-media-errors-during-backup-and-restore-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Fernando.